# I am trying to implement a call button in swift and the phone that appears is always the one of the first contact in the contacts array

Tags: swift, button, call

```
@IBAction func callButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let contact = contacts[sender.tag]
    self.makeCall(contact: contact)
}
func makeCall(contact: Characters){
    if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "tel://\(contact.phone)") {
        let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
        if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
            application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The phone appears, just the the right one. The "sender.tag" is suppose to give me the array number to which the phone belongs. Instead the phone that shows up is the one attached to the first object in the array.

Comment: Isn’t this a perfect time to use the debugger or print statements to check what sender.tags, contact etc is?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem by adding cell.callbutton.tag = indexPath.row to the cellForRowAt function.